# PHP, Twitter and Facebook posting pre-populated form content posting to own wall

Tags: php, facebook, post, twitter

Not sure if this has been done before, but did some searching and could not find anything.

I would like to have an input box on my webpage, which has some pre-populated text and when a user clicks submit the text is tweeted on their own wall, this would be posted immediately if they have a twitter session open if not twitter will ask for the user to sign in. I guess this must be possible because it is similar to a share button.

Not being very good with twitter I'm not sure where to even start.

(Also if possible I would like to do the same but with Facebook as well).

Nb. App is to be developed using php.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both twitter and facebook have well-documented API to do this. However, you will probably need to use their system to have the user confirm what is about to be posted. You might also need to use some javascript, I don't the specifics of these API.

https://dev.twitter.com/

https://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this on facebook. We do not allow pre-filling of the message param on dialogs.

Comment: I don't understand why Facebook does not allow this. Honestly, I would think that a VAST majority of the time, if an app is giving it's user the option to "share" something (text) to FB by posting on their wall, it will be something they see in the app or about the app. They user won't want to fill in text themselves. I'm asking honestly, I don't see the reason FB is disallowing this, especially when the API allows the ability to "auto-share" so the user doesn't even have to see the message